# Method call expected when writing an array

Tags: arrays, boolean, method-call, expected-exception

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] d=new double[500];
    for (int i = 0; i <500 ; i++) {
        d[i]= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    boolean[] disco=new boolean[500];
    for (int i = 0; i <500 ; i++) {
        disco[i]= false;
    }
    disco(5)=true;
}
```

}

I get an "method call expected" error when trying to change a value in the disco array. 
Could someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: disco(5)=false; should be disco[5]=false;

Answer (score 1):

To access an item in an array at a particular position use the square brackets notation.

```
disco[5]=false;
```

not

```
disco(5)=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `disco[5]` not `disco(5)`.

When you put () after disco, java is looking for a method disco that does not exist. To access an index of an array, you use [], square brackets.